# Cell blink and alternative rows color in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

As per stated on above. I'm looking for advises to increase my program performance. This program displays large amount of data with different colors for user to monitor on the overall system information. There are more than 20 major enhancement versions.  Recently I've received requirement to add "cell blink" in existing program. CPU processing go up to from 0~4% to 18~21% upon "cell blink" function is added.

For the data retrieval. It consists of more than 1 data grid views.
Upon dgv1 "detail" data source changed, then dgv2 will display dgv1 columns selectively, known as "summary" and set its data source.

```
    Private Sub dgv1_DataSourceChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgv1.DataSourceChanged

    ' Get data source from dgv1
    Dim dt1 As DataTable = dgvDetail.DataSource

    ' Select few columns from there     
    Dim selectedColumns As String() = New String() { ..... }
    Dim dt2 As DataTable = New DataView(dt1, String.Empty, String.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable(False, selectedColumns)

    ' Set dt2 back to dgv2
    dgv2.DataSource = dt2
End Sub
```

In order to show different colors on the data grid, based on cell values and also alternating rows color in dgv2. I'm using CellFormatting event to do this. The coding below has been simplified a lot. This chunk of code is perfectly fine in my program too.

```
    Private Sub dgv2_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgv2.CellFormatting

    ' Alternating rows color if previous row cell is different values 
    ' When current machineNo is different that previous row, then chg color
    ..... 

    ' Set colors based on values..
    ......
    ' Set colors based on values..

    ' Set colors based on values..

    ' Set colors based on values..

End Sub
```

Lastly, it's time to add cell blink function on a cell value. I've created a background worker to do the magic, adding to my form load to trigger this thread. So every 0.5 seconds, cell(3)(4) will be blinking with different colours!

```
    Dim _OnlyTwoColorChoices As Boolean 'for blinking purpose on TV screen

Private Sub backgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundWorker.DoWork
    While True
        If dgv2.IsDisposed Then
            Return
        Else
            If _cellList.Count > 0 Then
                If _OnlyTwoColorChoices = True Then
                    dgv2.Rows(3).Cells(14).Style.BackColor = Color.Pink
                Else
                    dgv2.Rows(3).Cells(14).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                End If

                ' Set to different value so that next flash will get different color
                _OnlyTwoColorChoices = Not _OnlyTwoColorChoices
            End If

            ' Blink frequency
            Thread.Sleep(500)
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

But then I've come to this performance issue. It consumes too much CPU time. Initially I suspect it's the cell blink function. But it's only few simple lines. I use diagnostic tool in VS2015 to find out the root cause of each spike on interval of 0.5 seconds. Is it really background worker's fault? The answer is NO. The culprit is dgv2_CellFormatting function. Every 0.5 seconds, it will trigger that function again and again.

> The CellFormatting event occurs every time each cell is painted

I've checked that the event is by default will be triggered whenever there's cell paint from [MS DataGridView CellFormating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)

My question is how do I can using both CellFormatting and CellBlink (Background worker) at the same time and not having performance issue? Please take note: instead of using background worker, i use Timer to achieve cell blink too, and the performance is not better either.

Comment: Given that your colors are set according to Data, why do you not simply have a routine to set colors on Data changed, rather than via CellFormatting event?  That way a blink will not cause all colors to be re-calculated.  This way you set the colors once on table load, and then re-set only if data changes.

Comment: I agree with @JonathanWillcock - `CellFormatting` is a resource hog of an event so I would strongly suggest moving your row coloring logic to only when the data changes.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock I  replaced cell formatting event for dgv2, with cell coloring instead. It reduces CPU time. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: @jaredbaszler Yes it reduces CPU time when cell formatting event is not used to paint the cells. The only thing I need to take care is re-set the colours whenever there's changes in data.